# Excluding a directory from webpack 1

Tags: webpack

Is there any option like **exclude**(which can be used in webpack 2+),for webpack `1.x`?

I am actually trying to exclude a module from webpack build .

I started exploring things on webpack recently. But couldn't find anything helpful.